# Dygraphs: graph is clipping out of the diagramm

Tags: android, html, dygraphs, clip-path

I'm using dygraphs to print a range selector diagramm in android. My problem is that the graph is going over the end of the diagramm div. This can be seen in the following picture.

[image]

On icanuse and different websites it says that android supported clip-path until 3.0. Since then clip-path isn't supported (I even tested it on LG G3 with android 5).

**My question:** Is there any workaround to prevent my graphs from clipping? Or do you have some ideas, which I could test?

**Related Links:**

https://code.google.com/p/dygraphs/issues/detail?id=200

http://dygraphs.com/tests/range-selector.html

https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/commit/971870e5232350812bf91dc7b555332a8993efda

Comment: Maybe it's time to remove the `.isAndroid()` check or make it more precise—I assume more modern Androids implement this correctly.

Comment: which is to say, please file an issue or (better) send a PR. It's not too late to get it into a 1.1.1 release.